# CTE or not for counting tree id's referenced in secondary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a simple tree table in which I reference types, sub-types (no level limit), brands and models for a simple inventory application.

data structure is as shown below: (nodeIsModel is a boolean field, used for calculations)

```
ID    parentID    label               nodeIsModel
 1     -1          Root                   0  
 2     1           IT                     0
 3     2           Desktops               0
 4     3           Hewlett-Packard        0 
 5     4           HP Z240                1
 6     4           H97M-PLUS              1
 7     2           Laptops                0
 8     7           DELL                   0
 9     8           G3 3579                1
```

and so on.

This table (displayed in a DBTreeView under Delphi) gives me something like:

```
ID     Label
1      Root
2        |_IT
3        |__Desktops
4        |___Hewlett-Packard
5        |____HP Z240
6        |____H97M-PLUS
7        |__Laptops
8        |___DELL
9        |____G3 3579
```

This table is the reference table in which the user will pick and assign to an equipment, a set of type, sub-types, brands and models.

Equipment is saved in another table (data_items) and linked to the previous table by the id of the selected model (lowest level of tree structure).

As an example, my desktop computer would be saved as:

```
itemID    itemLabel         typeID
  1       RSI-HP-DESK-01      5
```

because it's a HP Z240 workstation and it is referenced as ID 5 in the tree table.

Starting from this typeID, I have a CTE query that climbs up the tree to find all parents from child ID, this works no problem.

My question is as follows:

I would like, when displaying the DBTreeView, to had a column displaying:

- the item count for all models

but also

- the sum of **models** for each brand (counting the models)
- the sum of **models** for each sub-types
- the sum of **models** for each type...

and so on...

As an example, if we had 2 HP Z240 workstation and 1 DELL G3 laptop in database, the TreeView would look like:

```
ID     Label                    NB
1      Root
2        |_IT                   3
3        |__Desktops            2
4        |___Hewlett-Packard    2
5        |____HP Z240           1
6        |____H97M-PLUS         1
7        |__Laptops             1
8        |___DELL               1
9        |____G3 3579           1
```

Based on the "nodeIsModel" boolean field in the tree table, I have tried queries, some with CTE others without, but I am getting confused on the JOIN and sub-queries, also getting the error message about:

> aggregate queries not being allowed in CTE

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

---

*As per request of Dale K, here is the recursive query giving me all the parents starting from a child ID :*

**This query works. I am looking for a new query that would join the tree table with the item table giving a count on models assigned to items at each level of the tree**

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    ID,
    parentID,
    label,
    CAST (nodeLevel AS INTEGER) AS LEVEL
FROM
    dico_TBM
WHERE
    ID = :lookupID
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        r.ID,
        t.parentID,
        t.label,
        LEVEL - 1
    FROM
        dico_TBM t
    INNER JOIN CTE r ON t.ID = r.parentID
) SELECT DISTINCT
    r.ID,
    r.parentID,
    r.label,
    LEVEL
FROM
    CTE r
WHERE
    LEVEL > 0
ORDER BY
    LEVEL
```

(nodeLevel being an integer giving the level of the node in the tree I omitted to mention in my question, thinking it was of no interest, and :lookupID being the ID of the starting child node I pass as a parameter to my query)

Comment: @DaleK : question edited to show the CTE query used to retrieve all parents starting from a child node ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach which may help you solve the problem. Below is my similar setup
[image]

And the following query gives us the count of resources on each level in the resource tree.

```
;with CTE1 AS (
  SELECT r.id, r.label, r.parentID, count(*) AS ItemCount 
    FROM resourcetree r 
    JOIN items i ON (r.id = i.resourceID) 
   GROUP BY r.id, r.label, r.parentID
), 
CTE2 AS (
  SELECT r.id, r.label, r.parentID, SUM(cte1.itemCount) AS ItemCount, 0 AS sumFlag 
    FROM resourceTree r 
    JOIN CTE1 ON (r.id = cte1.parentID) 
   GROUP BY r.id, r.label, r.parentID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT r.id, r.label, r.parentID, cte2.ItemCount AS ItemCount, 1 AS sumFlag 
    FROM resourceTree r 
    JOIN cte2 ON (r.id = cte2.parentID)
)
SELECT r.id, 
       r.label, 
       COALESCE(c2_1.ItemCount, c2_0.ItemCount, cte1.ItemCount, 0) AS ItemCount 
  FROM resourceTree r 
  LEFT JOIN cte1 ON r.id = cte1.id 
  LEFT JOIN cte2 c2_0 ON (r.id = c2_0.id AND c2_0.sumFlag = 0)
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, label, SUM(ItemCount) AS ItemCount 
               FROM CTE2 
              WHERE sumFlag = 1 
              GROUP BY id, label) c2_1 ON r.id = c2_1.id
```

Below is the result I got. Hope it helps.
Thanks.

[image]

PS: I didn't have to use the 'NodeIsModel' flag

Comment: Exactly what I needed... have to admit it took me some time to digest and understand, but life savior. Thanks a million !

Answer (score 0):

Use `nodeIsModel = 1` as the anchor member of the `recursive cte` and starts from there and go up the level

```
with
rcte as
(
    select  *
    from    dico_TBM
    where   nodeIsModel = 1

    union all

    select  d.*
    from    rcte r
            inner join dico_TBM d   on  r.parnetID  = d.ID
)
select  ID, label, count(*) as NB
from    rcte
group by ID, label
order by ID
```

Comment: Nice effort : this gives me the number of reference by brand, sub types and types, but not the number of equipment attached to each model in my secondary table.

Comment: Useful nonetheless because I'll use it when displaying the types, sub-types, brands and models dictionary to the user. Thanks